# AngularJS v1.3.13 ng-view not triggering controller to render template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Having an issue using the ng-view to render a template from my controller. 
The index.html file is initially served to the client and looks like.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="hlmApp">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">

<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@Model.Root.Resource/bower_components\\/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">

@RenderSection("BootScript")

<!-- app.js will load the angular module -->
<script src="@Model.Root.Resource/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="@Model.Root.Resource/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="@Model.Root.Resource/app/app.js"></script>
<script src="@Model.Root.Resource/app/controllers/controllers.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="#/Overview">A link here</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-view></div>
    @*<div ng-controller="tempController">{{Heading}}</div>*@
</div>


@RenderBody()



</body>
</html>
```

the server pushes down my app.js and controllers.js file along with the deps.

```
/// ap.js ///
var hlmApp = angular.module('hlmApp', ['ngRoute', 'MyTempControllers']);

hlmApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/Holdings', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/temp.html',
        controller: 'controllers/tempController'
    });
}]);
```

the controller is pretty simple and is as follows

```
var MyTempControllers = angular.module('MyTempControllers', []);

MyTempControllers.controller('tempController', ['$scope', function () {
    console.log("stuff happening");
    $scope.Heading = "Hello World";
}]);
```

then the html template is as follows

```
<div>
    <h3>{{Heading}}</h3>
</div>
```

When I use the ng-view nothing ever renders. the controller is never triggered in the debugger. If I specifically call out the controller via the ng-controller then everything shows up. can someone point out my error here?

Comment: Try to change "controllers/tempController" for just "tempController". Why are you using the same controller to view and to heading?

Comment: just tried it. did not work. controllers and templates each have their own folder within the parent folder of 'app'

Comment: can you explain what you mean by *I specifically call out the controller via the ng-controller then everything shows up*.  is it this fragment in your HTML   `@*<div ng-controller="tempController">{{Heading}}</div>*@` (which shouldn't be needed)

Comment: You don't need to tell the path for the controller file. you just need to tell the controller name to your routeProvider

Comment: @MichaelColeman yes if I uncomment that line then 'Hello World' will show up on the page

Comment: and.... import controller file before your app.js

Comment: tried that. no luck :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need these 3 changes:

1) add $scope as a parameter in your controller function

```
MyTempControllers.controller('tempController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  ...
}]);
```

2.
Change

```
controller: 'controllers/tempController'
```

to

```
controller: 'tempController'
```

FYI, the naming convention for a controller is to begin with a capital letter for Controller.

3. In addition, you should add a

```
.otherwise({
  template: templates/temp.html,
  controller: 'tempController'
});
```

so that when no route matches, it goes to default-page-name.html. This is what's happening in your case, when you first load the page, no route matches. If you want to see temp.html, you have to 1) either click on a link that goes to #/Holdings, or 2) use '/Holdings' as the "otherwise" route, as indicated above.

Comment: seems to hit the otherwise in the route. Thanks!

Comment: You might want to look into ui-router (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) rather than using ng-router, since AngularJS is moving to something very similar to ui-router. in v1.4. I find it easier to use. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
hlmApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/Holdings', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/temp.html',
        controller: 'tempController' // just the name
    });
}]);
```

and also $scope is missing in parameters:

```
MyTempControllers.controller('tempController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    console.log("stuff happening");
    $scope.Heading = "Hello World";
}]);
```

Comment: Added $scope to the function params. good catch. however this did not work :(

Comment: It also seems you're missing an `ng-app` directive attribute. Try replacing your `<body>` tag with `<body ng-app='hlmApp'>`.

Comment: ng-app is in the html tag :) moved it to the body tag and still no luck :(